# .click() On Dynamically Named Element

Tags: jquery

I'm unsure of the terminology used in jquery, but I have this function:

```
$(function () {
    // open file explorer window
    $(".js-upload-photos").click(function () {
        // get the id of button
        var button_id = $(this).attr('id');
        // use this id to call correct fileupload input
        var fileupload = ("#fileupload").concat(button_id)
        $(fileupload).click();
    });
```

When my button is pressed, I get the `id` attached to it, then call the appropriate hidden `input` element.

I need my `$(...).click();` to be dynamic, as I have many of the same button/input pairs on my page for many different file uploads.

My current implementation doesn't work.

PS - I believe I need an `on()` method, but my attempts have failed.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you just trying to concatenate the id to the fileupload id?

```
$("#fileupload" + this.id).click();
```

If the elements are being added dynamically and you can use .on almost the same way:

```
$(".js-upload-photos").on('click', function(){
   $("#fileupload" + this.id).click();
});
```